# Switch an Access database between shared and exclusive mode?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I'm working on a program that needs to edit some objects in an Access database.  It also runs a subprogram (long story) that tries to access the underlying JET database *while Access still has it open* via ODBC.

The problem is that as soon as I start editing Form objects using VBA - for example, using Application.LoadFromText - Access changes the database to exclusive mode.  Exclusive mode itself is fine, and I know why it needs it.  But I need to be able to switch back to "shared" mode afterwards so that I can run my subprogram.

I've observed that if you use the UI to open a Form in Design mode, Access switches the database to Exclusive.  (You can confirm this by trying to open it from another computer.)  But when you then close the form designer, Access immediately switches it back to shared mode, which is what I would hope for.

Is there a way to switch it back and forth myself using VBA / COM calls?

I know I can call Application.CloseCurrentDatabase() followed by OpenCurrentDatabase(), but that closes all the windows and upsets the UI, so it's not ideal.

Comment: I found one workaround: open any form and then close it.  This seems to cause Access to reconsider whether it needs the database to stay in exclusive mode or not.  This is pretty gross, however.

Comment: Your question is confusing, as Access can't connect to its own data files (Jet/ACE) using ODBC.

Comment: Right, my subprogram is actually written in C++.  As long as Access doesn't have the .mdb file open, or it has it open in shared mode, the C++ program has no trouble manipulating it via ODBC.  (And it's about 10x faster than using DAO or ADO, or we would just borrow the DAO connection from the open Access database.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is splitting the database into a separate front-end with the forms/modules/etc. and back-end with the tables an option? That way if the front-end is locked, the back-end is still accessible. Access has a database splitting wizard for just that.

Comment: That's an option - and some databases where I'm doing that actually are split this way - but it's non-ideal.  I don't need to do operations *while* it's locked, I just need to be able to lock and unlock on demand.

Comment: Splitting is the only sensible answer.

Comment: If that's true, then it's sad. The databases in question are small and simple, and it's a shame to force them to split just because of a trivial locking issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might try .UserControl and .Visible.  I use them to transfer control in automated processes.

Comment: I'm not sure that will do anything of use.  The database is opened exclusively; that's not stopping the VBA app from controlling it.